# Will current_theme_supports return TRUE with a nonstandard add_theme_support?

Tags: plugin-development, add-theme-support

Will `current_theme_supports()` return TRUE with a nonstandard `add_theme_support()` string?

If I do this in my theme:

```
add_theme_support( 'my_funky_new_thing' );
```

Can someone else writing a plugin do this?

```
if( current_theme_supports( 'my_funky_new_thing' ) ){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can take advantage of this to enable or disable features in your plugin if a theme does or does not declare support for a feature. WooCommmerce is an example of a plugin that does this.

Answer (score 3):

As a side note for those interested, you can also pass parameters with your custom theme support.

```
// theme functions.php
add_theme_support( 'some_feature', array(
  'arg_foo',
  'arg_bar'
) );

// plugin.php
$feature_args = get_theme_support( 'some_feature' );
var_dump( $feature_args );
// array(
//   array(
//     'arg_foo',
//     'arg_bar'
//   )
// );
```